# How to find if an entry has parents (Playa) in a particular channel?

Tags: add-on, playa

Within my channel entries loop, I'm trying to determine if an entry has FAqs; which in this situation are the parent as you choose an entry in the FAQ.

This is what I have:
`{if '{exp:playa:total_parents channel="faqs" entry_id="{entry_id}"}' > 0}`

Which works-ish. It returns true for entries with no parent FAQs too. What am I doing wrong?

edit:

Parse order is set to input due to having some necessary PHP.

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="products" entry_id="<?php echo $entry_id; ?>" limit="1" dynamic="no" disable="categories|member_data|pagination"}
    {if {exp:playa:total_parents channel="faqs"} > 0}
        blah blah
    {/if}
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

Blah blah in this particular case returns whether or not there actually are FAQs.

Comment: Ryan, I think you may have some terminology reversed. Can you post a screenshot of one of your channel entries with a Playa relationship selected, as well as ore of your template code?  Version numbers (EE and Playa) would help as well!

Comment: The relationship is made in the FAQ entry. Based on the playa table, the FAQ is parent to the device. I choose a device that the FAQ pertains to. My template looks much like what Jean responded with below. EE  v2.5.5; Playa v4.4.2

Answer (score 1):

If your total_parents loop is inside your entries loop, you shouldn't need the entry id param since it defaults to that. So you should be able to do this:

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="my_channel" limit="1" dynamic="no" disable="whatever|not|needed" orderby="date" sort="desc"}
    {if '{exp:playa:total_parents channel="faqs" dynamic="no" disable="whatever|not|needed" orderby="date" sort="desc"}' > '0'}
        whatever you want if there are parent entries
    {/if}
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

This works only if the playa field is in the FAQ field group and that field is assigned to the channel used by your loop - is that where you have it?